# discord.js - Random user ID from reactions under message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to get random user ID from users with reaction under some message, but almost always when I'm trying to get all users with reaction it returns `No Winner` even if I reacted

Code:

```js
    setTimeout(()=> {
        // msg.reactions.removeAll
        if(msg.reactions.cache.get("").users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot).size > 0) {
            const winner = msg.reactions.cache.get("").users.cache.filter(user => !user.client).random().id
            message.channel.send(`Winner: @<${winner}>`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send("No winner.")
        }
    }, time-Date.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add

```js
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS to my intents.
```

Comment: Oo nice :) You can check my answer too. It's more readable and clean.

Comment: Yea, I did that, thanks a lot.

Comment: If this answer helped your problem please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when you can so it can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and it's working. You get `No winner` result every time because of `user.client`. You should use `user.bot`.

Here's a code I modified:

```
setTimeout(()=> {

  const reaction = message.reactions.cache.get("")
  const reactionUsers = reaction.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot)

  if(reactionUsers.size > 0){
    const winner = reactionUsers.random()
    const winnerId = winner.id
    message.channel.send(`Winner: <@${winnerId}>`)

  } else {
    message.channel.send(`No winner`)
  }
}, 10000)
```

**Change 1**: I used `user.bot` instead of `user.client`

**Change 2**: I assigned all variables before using them (It's more readable for me).

**Change 3**: `@<${winnerId}>` is **not correct**. Use `<@${winnerId}>` instead. (`@` should be inside of `<>` tag)